# Draw circle with image inside it on mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have to draw a circle and one small .png image inside it on the google mapview, can anyone suggest how to achieve it?

It should display circle on provided latitude and longitude and .png image should be there inside the circle.

I tried below code to draw a circle:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) lattitude,

                            (int) longitude);


@Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

              paint1 = new Paint();
              paint1.setARGB(128,0 , 0, 250);
              paint1.setStrokeWidth(2);
              paint1.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
              paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
              paint1.setDither(false);  
              paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
              paint1.setColor(Color.argb(128, 250, 135, 143));

              this.radius = 5000;

              Point pt = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, null);
              float projectedRadius =    mapView.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(radius);

              canvas.drawCircle(pt.x, pt.y, projectedRadius, paint1);

   }
```

I am able to draw a circle using above code on provided latitude and longitude but couldn't find a way to draw .png image inside the circle.
So idea is to draw circle with .png image inside it on provided latitude and longitude on the mapview.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I did something similar few days back. Should the image fill the circle or would it be like just present inside the circle like a marker or small icon?

Comment: Image should be inside the circle like a small icon and mostly it will be center of the circle.Please do share me the code if you have already implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would start by visualizing what the png-in-circle would look like and just make an image out of that. As in, make a png image of a circle with the png you wanted to show in it. Then, simply place an overlay at the desired lat/lon. See Part 2 of [this resource](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview).

Comment: png inside circle is nothing but one image inside the circle but circle itslef should not be any static image means when user zoome-in zoome out, circle should increase-decrease.

Comment: So, the circle needs to change size in proportion to the image itself? In that case, I would make the png an overlay itself and then draw the circle around it on the canvas. I'm not sure which method you're overriding above but you should override the mapView's onDraw(canvas) method instead. Store the location of your overlays in an array and, for every overlay, draw a circle around it's location in onDraw. Just make sure you call super.onDraw.

Comment: Is this v1 or v2 of the maps API btw?

Comment: its map API v2. I have overridden draw method of ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>

Comment: Thanks Halogen, I found the problem actually I missed to call super.draw , after calling this its works fine.